# How to move the obj directory correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to move my obj directory to another path with the file `Directory.Build.probs` with this content:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\obj</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But after this, all Nuget packages are marked with a yellow warning symbol and they are no longer available in the project.

What it the correct way, to move the obj folder from the project folder to the solution folder?

Comment: A solution may consist of more than one project. Therefore, you probably shouldn't attempt to move it from the project folder. Also, if someone else may be maintaining the code, it's best to follow standard practices.

Comment: **Why** are you doing this? Why do you believe that you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

While it is no longer recommended, we've been using the following settings in our `Directory.Build.props` for a long time, and it works fine, as long as you make sure that you don't have conflicting versions of dependencies in the solution.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IntermediateOutputPath>..\..\..\obj\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  <OutputPath>..\..\..\bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```